# How to Creator Earnings on Opensea (Polygon)

Tags: blockchain, polygon, wallet, nft, opensea

I have created collection on opensea and tried to add creator earnings.
even I set correct percentage ( below 10 ) and add payout wallet address.
but when I press submit change.
it show this error msg below submit change button.

> ['Payout address not valid']

when I tried on other collection deployed on Rinkeby, it works, only problem with Polygon.